# NSDateFormatter too slow in Time profiler

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Time profiler say that my code to expressive in memory and I see lags while scrolling tableView.

How can I replace this code?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[_duration doubleValue]];
return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

_duration have value 123

I need string from _duration like 2:03 sec

Comment: Create the formatter at the begining of the app, and keep it, reuse it. Example SO answer eg.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415384/shared-nsdateformatter-best-practices

Comment: @codedad, I tried use it in SharedInstance but I have 10-20 this calculations in cell and it not helps me

Comment: codedad's suggestion removes 95% of the cost of the code you've shown. If doing that (and doing it correctly) doesn't resolve your problem then it must be in code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1) Create the date formatter once and reuse it.

2) Don't use a date formatter. There's no need. It's trivial to convert your duration to minutes and seconds.

```
int duration = [_duration intValue];
int mins = duration / 60;
int secs = duration % 60;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", mins, secs];
```

Comment: ... would you not need an explicit cast to turn the double into an int, for the modulus at least? It's the first warning I switch on in a new project but, even if not, we might as well start getting into the Swift mindset, right?

Comment: @Tommy The question is about Objective-C code. If someone cranks up the warnings and the code in this answer complains about the type conversion, then adding appropriate casts would be the right thing to do. I have no desire to get in the Swift mindset. :)

Comment: int secs = (int)duration % 60;